# Ion-datetime won't update view value after change in controller

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to validate two dates, initial and final. So if the initial date is after the final, then the initial should take the final value and so on. The model and view are correctly updated with some workarounds.

Let's say I try to change the initial date again, the picker starts selection on the last value picked, which was the initial date being after the final, instead of the current value in model.

```
<p class="data" text-left (click)="initialDatePicker.open()">{{initialDateView}}
  <ion-datetime #initialDatePicker [displayFormat]="configIonDateTime.displayFormat"
    [cancelText]="configIonDateTime.cancelText" [(ngModel)]="initialDate" [value]="initialDate"
    [min]="configIonDateTime.dateToday" [doneText]="configIonDateTime.doneText" picker-format="DD MMMM YYYY"
    [monthNames]="configIonDateTime.monthNames" [monthShortNames]="configIonDateTime.monthShortNames"
    [dayNames]="configIonDateTime.dayNames" [dayShortNames]="configIonDateTime.dayShortNames"
    (ionChange)="changeDates(1)" [hidden]="true">
  </ion-datetime>
</p>
```

```
changeDates(option) {

  switch (option) {

    case 1:
      if (moment(this.initialDate).isAfter(moment(this.dataValidade))) {
        this.initialDate = this.finalDate;
        this.initialDateView = moment(this.initialDate).format('L');
        this.getInitialDat.emit(this.initialDate);
        return;
      }
      this.initialDateView = moment(this.initialDate).format('L');
      this.getInitialDate.emit(this.initialDate);
      break;

    case 2:
      if (moment(this.finalDate).isBefore(moment(this.initialDate))) {
        this.finalDate = this.initialDate;
        this.finalDateView = moment(this.finalDate).format('L');
        this.getDataValidade.emit(this.finalDate);
        return;
      }
      this.finalDateView = moment(this.finalDate).format('L');
      this.getFinalDate.emit(this.finalDate);
      break;

  }

}
```

I need the values on the picker to update correctly according to the model

Comment: Please specify your actual error